# Template databases in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL to work with data. I typed `\l` command to see my current databases, but there are already 2 databases. I die not create them by myself.

They are called as `template0` and `template1`. What is that? What do they exist for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are system databases that are used as templates when a new database is created.

This is [explained in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html):

> `CREATE DATABASE` actually works by copying an existing database. By default, it copies the standard system database named `template1`. Thus that database is the “template” from which new databases are made. If you add objects to `template1`, these objects will be copied into subsequently created user databases.

> [...]

> There is a second standard system database named `template0`. This database contains the same data as the initial contents of `template1`, that is, only the standard objects predefined by your version of PostgreSQL. `template0` should never be changed after the database cluster has been initialized. By instructing `CREATE DATABASE` to copy `template0` instead of `template1`, you can create a “virgin” user database that contains none of the site-local additions in `template1`.